# How to Match Start Date and End Date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In the above documentation When u pass 2 parameters having start date and end date.how to apply the codition   If the 2 parameters dates are matched (eg: yesterday date – today date)

```
var start = ISODate("2018-04-19T18:32:50.000Z");
var end =ISODate("2018-04-20T20:32:50.000Z");

db.collection.aggregate([
   {$match : { "CREATEDATE" : { $gte:start, $lt:end} } },
   {"$sort":{"CREATEDATE":1}},
   {"$group":{
    "_id":"$DATA_FROM",
    "MAXDATE":{"$last":"$$ROOT"}

  }},


])
```

Comment: What is the question? You have two dates there so what actually do you expect to happen?

Comment: @  Neil Lunn Iam expecting startdate match with yesterday date and enddate match with today date it is true apply onecondition the condition is false apply anothe condition please suggest me

Comment: You might need to ask someone with assistance posting to an english language site such as this. From what I can gather, you likely mean what is covered in the duplicate question. If you do not, then please seek some assistance in making a clearer translation of what you actually need. I've pointed you to the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) statement on many occasions before. If you don't understand that, then please get someone to translate that for you as well.